# Add information from a CSV file to a URL

Tags: xml, perl, csv

I need to make multiple HTTP PUT requests.

I have an XML template for them, and a CSV file with IDs, names and IPs from my devices. (I want to change names or IPs in my system).

The devices have exactly the IDs in my CSV data.

#### Input.csv (id, name, ip)

```
123,test1, 10.56.22.1
124,test2, 10.56.2
```

#### My Perl script

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Headers;
use HTTP::Request;
use File::Slurp;
use JSON -support_by_pp;
use LWP 5.64;
use MIME::Base64;
use IO::Socket::SSL;
use File::Slurp;

# Create a user agent object
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( ssl_opts => {
    SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE(),
    verify_hostname => 0,
} );

my $xml = XML::Twig->new->parsefile ('iemplate.xml');
$xml->set_pretty_print('indented_a');

open ( my $input, '<', 'input.csv' ) or die $!;

    while ( <$input> ) {
        chomp;
        my ($id, $name, $ip) = split /,/;

        $xml->root->set_att('name', $name);
        $xml->get_xpath('//ipaddress', 0)->set_text($ip);

        my $uri = 'https://hostname:9060/ers/config/networkdevice/($id)';
        my $req = HTTP::Request->new('PUT', $uri, [
            Accept       => 'application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.network.networkdevice.1.1+xml',
            Content_Type => 'application/vnd.com.cisco.ise.network.networkdevice.1.1+xml;charset=utf-8'
        ],
        $xml->sprint
    );

    $req->content($xml->sprint);
    $req->authorization_basic("user", "user");

    # Pass request to the user agent and get a response back
    my $res = $ua->request($req);

    # Check the outcome of the response
    if ($res->is_success) {
        print $res->status_line, "n";
    }
    else {
        print $res->status_line, "n";
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> 404 Not Found

But I know that these IDs are in my system. How should I add my IDs to the URL for doing multiple PUT requests?

Comment: 404 means the URI you're accessing doesn't exist. Try doing `curl` to talk to it - you can `curl -XPUT`

Comment: Is `$uri` correct? Add a line after populating it to print it out so you can verify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious problem is that `$uri` won't be expanded in this statement

```
my $uri = 'https://hostname:9060/ers/config/networkdevice/($id)'
```

There are no embedded double-quotes in the string, so there's no problem with using them as delimiters, which *will* interpolate the scalar

```
my $uri = "https://hostname:9060/ers/config/networkdevice/($id)"
```

I cannot guarantee that this will solve the immediate problem as I have no way of testing it, but it seems likely

Comment: `my $uri = "https://hostname:9060/ers/config/networkdevice/$id"` this is a right way to write. `id` without clips